# Django ckeditor upload image

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm trying to use ckeditor to upload an image. Looks like everything is set up by documentation, but still I'm getting an error while trying to upload an image. I think that there is a problem with static files. Looks like ckeditor doesn't know where to upload files, even though I've provided all needed parameters:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
```

I'm getting this message:

```
[23/Feb/2020 20:17:47] "POST /ckeditor/upload/&responseType=json HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

[And here's what I get in browser. The red one is for "incorrect server response".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gSfr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with 'static' folder location in my project. I've solved my problem adding

```
CKEDITOR_STORAGE_BACKEND = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
```

To my settings file. Not sure if it will work for you, but it definitely works for me since 'FileSystemStorage' looks for 'MEDIA_ROOT' setting by default.